# Regex to locate any string of numbers next to any string of letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to use Regex to find any amount of numbers next to any amount of letters and insert a "*" between them. So, for example the code would turn...

```
2s
z10
30000000000kh
```

...into...

```
2*s
z*10
30000000000*kh
```

I have tried using:

```
string.replace(/(?:[0-9]+)(?=(?:[a-z.]+))/g)
   .replace(/(?:[a-z]+)(?=(?:[0-9]+))/g);
```

...to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: try usinf the `\D` operator for digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find the transition between digits and non-digits or vice versa and then insert an asterisk in between the match:

```
str.replace(/\d[a-z]|[a-z]\d/i, function($0) {
    return $0[0] + '*' + $0[1]; 
});
```

Comment: This is close, but it is also inserting an asterisk between numbers and characters. For instance "4+4" is becoming "4*+4". Is there a way to limit it to just to letters?

Answer (score 3):

use this pattern `([a-z])(?=\d)|(\d)(?=[a-z])`
and replace with `$1$2*`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/zA9rV8)

Comment: kind of confusing, but interesting :]